# Custom validator with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following class:

```
class PatientPaymentSpreadsheetRow < ApplicationSpreadsheetRow
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validate :date_format

  def date_format
    unless value('Transaction').split('/').last.length == 4
      errors.add('Transaction', 'date format invalid')
    end
  end
end
```

This particular validation happens to act on `value('Transaction')`. I'd like my validator to be sufficiently generic that I can pass in any value (e.g. `value('Date of birth')`) and have it act on that value.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom 'each validator', like described in [Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators):

```
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(model, attribute, value)
    return if value.split('/').last.length == 4
    model.errors.add(attribute, 'date format invalid')
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
class MyCustomModel
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :my_date_attr
  validates :my_date_attr, date_format: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with something similar to this. I don't believe this approach actually would have worked with my original code since `value('Transaction')` isn't an attribute on my model. I decided to modify my class so that an attribute called `transaction` would point to `value('Transaction')`. This enabled me to use `ActiveModel::EachValidator`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I think this is more in the ballpark of what you were asking.

`ActiveModel::EachValidator` allows you to pass in `options` as a hash, which will be available in the class instance with `options`.

You can set up the validation in your model like

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates :transaction, date_format: { value: 'Transaction' }
end
```

And the custom validator would look like:

```rb
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(model, attribute, value)
    return if options[:value].split('/').last.length == 4
    #         ^^^^^^^ hash you pass is here
    model.errors.add(attribute, 'date format invalid')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

But presumably you want the validations to run unconditionally, so...

```
validate :date_format
DATES_TO_VALIDATE = ['Transaction', 'Date of birth', 'Other date']

def date_format
  DATES_TO_VALIDATE.each do |key|
    unless value(key).split('/').last.length == 4
      errors.add(key, 'date format invalid')
    end
  end
end
```

This can be extracted to an `each_validator` as per Marek Lipka's answer, with a custom constant `DATES_TO_VALIDATE` for each model and access it in the validator as `model.class::DATES_TO_VALIDATE`